# sql query for latest invoice for each product for each customer

Tags: sql, group-by

I have `invoice` and `invoice_detail` tables. `invoice_detail` table has `product_detail_id` column. `invoice` table have `create_date` and `customer_id` columns. `invoice_detail` table has `gross_total` column.

```
invoice
    id
    customer_id
    create_date
    billing_type

invoice_detail
    invoice_id
    product_detail_id
    quantity
    gross_total
```

I need to find `gross_total` amount of the specific `product_detail_id`**s** for the latest sell, that it is the current price of the product for the specific customer. How can i query this data?

my current query is like below, I want to rewrite it using the criteria builder in Java So I need to rewrite it without using inner select.

```
select ivd.product_detail_id, iv.customer_id, ivd.gross_total / ivd.quantity from (
select * from (
    select
        id,
        create_date,
        customer_id,
        row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by create_date desc) as rn
    from
        invoice
    where billing_type = 'SELLING'
    and customer_id = 20465--parameter
) t
where t.rn = 1
) iv
left join invoice_detail ivd on iv.id = ivd.invoice_id
where 
ivd.product_detail_id  in (1,2,3, 56569, 56571)
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: There's no point doing a left join and then filtering on the inner table.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any sample data, so I made some up:

```
create table #invoice
(
    id int,
    customer_id int,
    create_date date,
    billing_type varchar(50)
)

create table #invoice_detail
(
    invoice_id int,
    product_detail_id int,
    quantity int,
    gross_total int
)

insert into #invoice values
(1,20465,'2023-07-07','SELLING'),
(2,20465,'2023-07-08','SELLING'),
(3,20465,'2023-07-08','SELLING'),
(4,20465,'2023-07-09','SELLING'),
(5,20465,'2023-07-10','SELLING'),
(6,20465,'2023-07-11','SELLING')

insert into #invoice_detail values
(1,1,3,300),
(1,2,2,1000),
(1,56569,1,2500),
(2,1,4,440),
(2,2,3,1500),
(3,1,10,1250),
(3,2,4,2000),
(3,56571,2,20000),
(4,1,6,780),
(4,2,9,4500),
(5,1,20,2600),
(6,1,3,360)
```

Your attempt was pretty close, I think you just forgot to also partition by `product_detail_id`:

```
with summary as
(
    select
        i.customer_id,
        id.product_detail_id,
        i.create_date,
        id.gross_total / id.quantity as unit_value,
        row_number() over (partition by i.customer_id, id.product_detail_id order by i.create_date desc) as rn
    from #invoice_detail id
    join #invoice i on id.invoice_id = i.id
    where i.billing_type = 'SELLING'
    and customer_id = 20465
    and id.product_detail_id in (1,2,3,56569,56571)
)

select 
    customer_id, 
    product_detail_id, 
    create_date, 
    unit_value 
from summary 
where rn = 1
```

This gives the most recent unit value for each product (for each customer, although my sample data doesn't contain any other customers):

```
/------------------------------------------------------------\
| customer_id | product_detail_id | create_date | unit_value |
|-------------|-------------------|-------------|------------|
|    20465    |         1         | 2023-07-11  |     120    |
|    20465    |         2         | 2023-07-09  |     500    |
|    20465    |     56569         | 2023-07-07  |    2500    |
|    20465    |     56571         | 2023-07-08  |   10000    |
\------------------------------------------------------------/
```

If you prefer not to use a CTE, you can just do it with a subquery:

```
select
    customer_id, 
    product_detail_id, 
    create_date, 
    unit_value 
from
(
    select
        i.customer_id,
        id.product_detail_id,
        i.create_date,
        id.gross_total / id.quantity as unit_value,
        row_number() over (partition by i.customer_id, id.product_detail_id order by i.create_date desc) as rn
    from #invoice_detail id
    join #invoice i on id.invoice_id = i.id
    where i.billing_type = 'SELLING'
    and customer_id = 20465
    and id.product_detail_id in (1,2,3,56569,56571)
) r
where r.rn = 1
```